# If set of divisors of elements of a difference set $\Delta S = S - S \subset R$ a commutative ring is the whole ring (!) then $\Delta S$ is an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, difference-sets

Let $R$ be an infinite commutative ring.  Let $S \subset R$ be such that $\Delta S = \{ s - s' : s,s' \in S\}$ has the properties:

1. $$
   \forall a \in R\setminus 0,\  a \textbf{ divides } g \textbf{ for } \infty\textbf{-many } g \in \Delta S
   $$

In other words the set of divisors of elements of $\Delta S$ is the whole ring!   And each divisor occurs infinitely often!

Is there some way we can conclude that $\Delta S$ forms an ideal of $R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $S=\{n!: n\geq k\}$.

Comment: What if we stipulate that $\gcd(S) = 1$?

Comment: Just choose $k=1$.

Comment: Suppose further, $S \not\ni 1$!

Comment: With $k=1$, we have $1\in S$ and also $1\in\Delta S$, so $\gcd S=\gcd\Delta S=1$ but $\Delta S\neq R$

Comment: If you don't want $1\in S$, just shift $S$ to $S+\ell$ for some $\ell\in R$.

Comment: What if additionally $\Delta S + \Delta S = I \leqslant R$ is an ideal

Comment: It is very easy to choose another example.